# How to export multiple data table after searching in custom search bar in excel sheet and pdf on their respective button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I want to export multiple data tables into excel & Pdf on their respective button click after searching a keyword in custom search bar.

I've written a code which was working fine for exporting PDF after searching keywords but aftet modifying it for excel generation my keyword search stop working.
Please help, I don't know where I'm missing the things.

Attaching my code :

```js
//My Code
$(document).ready( function() {
    var tables  = document.querySelectorAll('.data-table');
    var tableElements = [];
    var tableArr = [];
    var tableContent = [];

    

    //Export to Excel
    function getHeaderNames(table) {
      // Gets header names.
      //params:
      //  table: table ID.
      //Returns:
      //  Array of column header names.

      var header = $(table).DataTable().columns().header().toArray();

      var names = [];
      header.forEach(function(th) {
        names.push($(th).attr('data-exportname'));
      });

      return names;
    }

    function buildCols(data) {
      // Builds cols XML.
      //To do: define widths for each column.
      //Params:
      //  data: row data.
      //Returns:
      //  String of XML formatted column widths.

      var cols = '<cols>';

      for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        colNum = i + 1;
        cols += '<col min="' + colNum + '" max="' + colNum + '" width="20" customWidth="1"/>';
      }

      cols += '</cols>';

      return cols;
    }

    function buildRow(data, rowNum, styleNum) {
      // Builds row XML.
      //Params:
      //  data: Row data.
      //  rowNum: Excel row number.
      //  styleNum: style number or empty string for no style.
      //Returns:
      //  String of XML formatted row.

      var style = styleNum ? ' s="' + styleNum + '"' : '';

      var row = '<row r="' + rowNum + '">';

      for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        colNum = (i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();  // Convert to alpha

        var cr = colNum + rowNum;

        row += '<c t="inlineStr" r="' + cr + '"' + style + '>' +
          '<is>' +
          '<t>' + data[i] + '</t>' +
          '</is>' +
          '</c>';
      }

      row += '</row>';

      return row;
    }

    function getTableData(table, title) {
      // Processes Datatable row data to build sheet.
      //Params:
      //  table: table ID.
      //  title: Title displayed at top of SS or empty str for no title.
      //Returns:
      //  String of XML formatted worksheet.

      var header = getHeaderNames(table);
      var table = $(table).DataTable();
      var rowNum = 1;
      var mergeCells = '';
      var ws = '';

      ws += buildCols(header);
      ws += '<sheetData>';

      if (title.length > 0) {
        ws += buildRow([title], rowNum, 51);
        rowNum++;

        mergeCol = ((header.length - 1) + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();

        mergeCells = '<mergeCells count="1">'+
          '<mergeCell ref="A1:' + mergeCol + '1"/>' +
          '</mergeCells>';
      }

      ws += buildRow(header, rowNum, 2);
      rowNum++;

      // Loop through each row to append to sheet.    
      table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {

        var rowData = [];
        //var data = this.data();

        var rowNode = this.node();

        $(rowNode).find("td:visible").each(function () {
          var cellData = $(this).attr('data-exportname');
          rowData.push(cellData);
        });

        // If data is object based, then it needs to be converted 
        // to an array before sending to buildRow()
        ws += buildRow(rowData, rowNum, '');

        rowNum++;
      } );

      ws += '</sheetData>' + mergeCells;

      return ws;

    }

    function setSheetName(xlsx, name) {
      // Changes tab title for sheet.
      //Params:
      //  xlsx: xlxs worksheet object.
      //  name: name for sheet.

      if (name.length > 0) {
        var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
        source.setAttribute('name', name);
      }
    }

    function addSheet(xlsx, table, title, name, sheetId) {
      //Clones sheet from Sheet1 to build new sheet.
      //Params:
      //  xlsx: xlsx object.
      //  table: table ID.
      //  title: Title for top row or blank if no title.
      //  name: Name of new sheet.
      //  sheetId: string containing sheetId for new sheet.
      //Returns:
      //  Updated sheet object.

      //Add sheet2 to [Content_Types].xml => <Types>
      //============================================
      var source = xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Override')[1];
      var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
      clone.setAttribute('PartName','/xl/worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
      xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Types')[0].appendChild(clone);

      //Add sheet relationship to xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels => Relationships
      //=====================================================================
      var source = xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationship')[0];
      var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
      clone.setAttribute('Id','rId'+sheetId+1);
      clone.setAttribute('Target','worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
      xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationships')[0].appendChild(clone);

      //Add second sheet to xl/workbook.xml => <workbook><sheets>
      //=========================================================
      var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
      var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
      clone.setAttribute('name', name);
      clone.setAttribute('sheetId', sheetId);
      clone.setAttribute('r:id','rId'+sheetId+1);
      xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheets')[0].appendChild(clone);

      //Add sheet2.xml to xl/worksheets
      //===============================
      var newSheet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
          '<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">'+
          getTableData(table, title) +

          '</worksheet>';

      xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet' + sheetId + '.xml'] = $.parseXML(newSheet);

    }


    tableElements = tables.forEach( (element, index) => {
      if(index != 0) {
        return $(element).DataTable();
      }

      return $(element).DataTable({
        dom: 'Bftrip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Excel',
            exportOptions: {
              orthogonal: "sort",
              format: {
                header: function (data, column, node){
                  if(node.dataset.exportname != undefined){
                    return node.dataset.exportname;
                  }
                  return data;
                },
                body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                  if(node.dataset.exportname != null){
                    return node.dataset.exportname;
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }
            },
            customize: function( xlsx ) {
              setSheetName(xlsx, 'Employees');

              // process additional DataTables in the web page:
              $('table').each(function( index ) {
                if ( index > 0 ) {
                  var tableID = '#' + $( this ).attr('id');
                  var rowOneTitle = $( this ).attr('data-rowonetitle');
                  var sheetName = $( this ).attr('data-sheetname');
                  var sheetID = index + 1;
                  addSheet(xlsx, tableID, rowOneTitle, sheetName, sheetID);
                }
              });

            }
          }
        ]
      });
    });

    //Export to PDF
    $('#ExportPdf').click(function(){
      var config = {
        className:"buttons-pdf buttons-html5",
        customize:null,
        download:"download",
        exportOptions:{
          format: {
            header: function (data, column, node){
              if(node.dataset.exportname != null){
                return node.dataset.exportname;
              }
              return data;
            },
            body: function (data, row, column, node) {
              if(node.dataset.exportname != null){
                return node.dataset.exportname;
              }
              return data;
            }
          }
        },
        extension:".pdf",
        filename:"*",
        header:true,
        namespace:".dt-button-2",
        orientation:"portrait",
        pageSize:"A4",
        title:"*"
      };

      tables.forEach((element, index) => {
        var dataTable = $(element).DataTable();
        var data = dataTable.buttons.exportData( config.exportOptions );
        var info = dataTable.buttons.exportInfo( config );
        var rows = [];

        if (config.header) {
          rows.push($.map(data.header, function (d) {
            return {
              text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
              style: 'tableHeader'
            };
          }));
        }

        for (var i=0, ien=data.body.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
          rows.push($.map(data.body[i], function ( d ) {
            return {
              text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
              style: i % 2 ? 'tableBodyEven' : 'tableBodyOdd'
            };
          }));
        }

        tableContent.push(
          { 
            text: tableArr[index]
          }
        );

        tableContent.push({
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            body: rows,
          },
          margin: [ 0, 2, 0, 20 ], // left, top, right, bottom
          layout: "noBorders",
        });
      });

      var doc = {
        pageSize: config.pageSize,
        pageOrientation: config.orientation,
        content: tableContent,
        styles: {
          tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154',
            alignment: 'center'
          },
          tableBodyEven: {},
          tableBodyOdd: {
            fillColor: '#f3f3f3'
          },
          tableFooter: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154'
          },
          title: {
            alignment: 'center',
            fontSize: 15
          },
          message: {}
        },
        defaultStyle: {
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }; 


      if ( config.customize ) {
        config.customize( doc, config );
      }
      pdfMake.createPdf(doc).download('Vehicle Status Report.pdf');
    });

    $('#mySearch').on( 'keyup click', function () {
      tableElements.forEach(element => {
        element.tables().search($(this).val()).draw();
      });
    });
    $('.dataTables_filter').addClass('hide-elements');
  });
```

```css
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }

  .hide-elements{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<button id="ExportPdf" type="button">Export All</button>
Custom Search: <input type="search" id="mySearch">
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 1" data-rowonetitle="Table 1" id="table-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company1</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact1</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Alfreds Futterkiste">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td data-exportname="Maria Anders">Maria Anders</td>
      <td data-exportname="Germany">Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Centro comercial Moctezuma">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td data-exportname="Francisco Chang">Francisco Chang</td>
      <td data-exportname="Mexico">Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Ernst Handel">Ernst Handel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Roland Mendel">Roland Mendel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Austria">Austria</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 2" data-rowonetitle="Table 2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Alfreds Futterkiste">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td data-exportname="Maria Anders">Maria Anders</td>
      <td data-exportname="Germany">Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 3" data-rowonetitle="Table 3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Centro comercial Moctezuma">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td data-exportname="Francisco Chang">Francisco Chang</td>
      <td data-exportname="Mexico">Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Ernst Handel">Ernst Handel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Roland Mendel">Roland Mendel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Austria">Austria</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made changes in few lines in my own code and got the expected output.
I've pushed the data table object to the same tableElement array and my custom search started working absolutely fine also Excel file generation starts working with the desired output.

**Pushed Data table object into the same tableElement Array due to which my custom search starts working**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll('.data-table');
    var tableArr = [];
    var tableContent = [];
    var tableElements = [];
    var dataTableObj;
    tables.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (index != 0) {
            let tableEle = $(element).DataTable();
            //Pushed data table 1 object to tableElements array
            tableElements.push(tableEle);
            tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
            return;
        }

        var tableEle = $(element).DataTable({
            dom: 'Bftrip',
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                
                //Added custom title of Excel
                title: 'Demo Excel',
                text: 'Excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    //same code
                },
                customize: function(xlsx) {
                    //Same code

                }
            }]
        });
        
        //Pushed other data table objects into the same tableElements array
        tableElements.push(tableEle);
        tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
    });

    $('#ExportPdf').click(function() {
        //Same Code
    });

    $('#mySearch').on('keyup click', function() {
        //Same code
    });

    $('.dataTables_filter').addClass('hide-elements');
});

// Function generating Excel files are defined outside of document.ready()
function getHeaderNames(table) {
    // Gets header names.
    //params:
    //  table: table ID.
    //Returns:
    //  Array of column header names.

    var header = $(table).DataTable().columns().header().toArray();

    var names = [];
    header.forEach(function(th) {
        names.push($(th).attr('data-exportname'));
    });

    return names;
}

function buildCols(data) {
    // Builds cols XML.
    //To do: define widths for each column.
    //Params:
    //  data: row data.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted column widths.

    var cols = '<cols>';

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        colNum = i + 1;
        cols += '<col min="' + colNum + '" max="' + colNum + '" width="20" customWidth="1"/>';
    }

    cols += '</cols>';

    return cols;
}

function buildRow(data, rowNum, styleNum) {
    // Builds row XML.
    //Params:
    //  data: Row data.
    //  rowNum: Excel row number.
    //  styleNum: style number or empty string for no style.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted row.

    var style = styleNum ? ' s="' + styleNum + '"' : '';

    var row = '<row r="' + rowNum + '">';

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        colNum = (i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase(); // Convert to alpha

        var cr = colNum + rowNum;

        row += '<c t="inlineStr" r="' + cr + '"' + style + '>' +
            '<is>' +
            '<t>' + data[i] + '</t>' +
            '</is>' +
            '</c>';
    }

    row += '</row>';

    return row;
}

function getTableData(table, title) {
    // Processes Datatable row data to build sheet.
    //Params:
    //  table: table ID.
    //  title: Title displayed at top of SS or empty str for no title.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted worksheet.

    var header = getHeaderNames(table);
    var table = $(table).DataTable();
    var rowNum = 1;
    var mergeCells = '';
    var ws = '';

    ws += buildCols(header);
    ws += '<sheetData>';

    if (title.length > 0) {
        ws += buildRow([title], rowNum, 51);
        rowNum++;

        mergeCol = ((header.length - 1) + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();

        mergeCells = '<mergeCells count="1">' +
            '<mergeCell ref="A1:' + mergeCol + '1"/>' +
            '</mergeCells>';
    }

    ws += buildRow(header, rowNum, 2);
    rowNum++;

    // Loop through each row to append to sheet.    
    table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

        var rowData = [];
        //var data = this.data();

        var rowNode = this.node();

        $(rowNode).find("td:visible").each(function() {
            var cellData = $(this).attr('data-exportname');
            rowData.push(cellData);
        });

        // If data is object based, then it needs to be converted 
        // to an array before sending to buildRow()
        ws += buildRow(rowData, rowNum, '');

        rowNum++;
    });

    ws += '</sheetData>' + mergeCells;

    return ws;

}

function setSheetName(xlsx, name) {
    // Changes tab title for sheet.
    //Params:
    //  xlsx: xlxs worksheet object.
    //  name: name for sheet.

    if (name.length > 0) {
        var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
        source.setAttribute('name', name);
    }
}

function addSheet(xlsx, table, title, name, sheetId) {
    //Clones sheet from Sheet1 to build new sheet.
    //Params:
    //  xlsx: xlsx object.
    //  table: table ID.
    //  title: Title for top row or blank if no title.
    //  name: Name of new sheet.
    //  sheetId: string containing sheetId for new sheet.
    //Returns:
    //  Updated sheet object.

    //Add sheet2 to [Content_Types].xml => <Types>
    //============================================
    var source = xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Override')[1];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('PartName', '/xl/worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
    xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Types')[0].appendChild(clone);

    //Add sheet relationship to xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels => Relationships
    //=====================================================================
    var source = xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationship')[0];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('Id', 'rId' + sheetId + 1);
    clone.setAttribute('Target', 'worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
    xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationships')[0].appendChild(clone);

    //Add second sheet to xl/workbook.xml => <workbook><sheets>
    //=========================================================
    var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('name', name);
    clone.setAttribute('sheetId', sheetId);
    clone.setAttribute('r:id', 'rId' + sheetId + 1);
    xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheets')[0].appendChild(clone);

    //Add sheet2.xml to xl/worksheets
    //===============================
    var newSheet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' +
        '<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">' +
        getTableData(table, title) +

        '</worksheet>';

    xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet' + sheetId + '.xml'] = $.parseXML(newSheet);

}
```

```css
/* Same CSS*/
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<button id="ExportPdf" type="button">Export to PDF</button>
Custom Search: <input type="search" id="mySearch">

<!--Added RowOneTitle above each table-->
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 1" data-rowOneTitle="Table 1">
  <thead>
    Some Code
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    Some code
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- More Tables-->
```

```js
tables.forEach((element, index) => {
      if(index != 0) {
        let tableEle = $(element).DataTable();
        tableElements.push(tableEle);
        tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
        return;
      }
      
      var tableEle = $(element).DataTable({
        dom: 'Bftrip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: 'Vehicle Status Report',
            text: 'Excel',
            exportOptions: {
              orthogonal: "sort",
              format: {
                header: function (data, column, node){
                  if(node.dataset.exportname != undefined){
                    return node.dataset.exportname;
                  }
                  return data;
                },
                body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                  if(node.dataset.exportname != null){
                    return node.dataset.exportname;
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }
            },
            customize: function( xlsx ) {
              setSheetName(xlsx, 'Employees');

              // process additional DataTables in the web page:
              $('table').each(function( index ) {
                if ( index > 0 ) {
                  var tableID = '#' + $( this ).attr('id');
                  var rowOneTitle = $( this ).attr('data-rowonetitle');
                  var sheetName = $( this ).attr('data-sheetname');
                  var sheetID = index + 1;
                  addSheet(xlsx, tableID, rowOneTitle, sheetName, sheetID);
                }
              });

            }
          }
        ]
      });
      tableElements.push(tableEle);
      tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
    });
```

```js
tables.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (index != 0) {
        let tableEle = $(element).DataTable();
        //Pushing DataTable Element into same array
        tableElements.push(tableEle);
        tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
        return;
    }

    var tableEle = $(element).DataTable({
        //My Code......
    });
    
    //Pushing DataTable Element into same array
    tableElements.push(tableEle);
    tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);
});
```