# Hide rows using custom dropdowns in data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

With respect to my previous question:
[How to export multiple data table after searching in custom search bar in excel sheet and pdf on their respective button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75963619/how-to-export-multiple-data-table-after-searching-in-custom-search-bar-in-excel)

I now want to integrate my custom dropdowns to hide data table rows. So, is there any css class which data table also use to hide rows so that I also can add the same to the rows while hiding or I need to add my own implementation in data table search.
I'm refering to [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) link to write my code but not able to do so properly.

Comment: "_not able to do so properly_" - Can you clarify the specific problem? What is preventing you from adding drop-downs to your DataTable (or to each of your DataTables, if you have more than one on your web page)? Can you provide a [mre]? And because your other question has a _large_ amount of code already, can you focus on the "m" (_minimal_) part of your MRE?